# What is the difference between AngularJS $window.alert() and Javascript alert()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, alert

It seems that the AngularJS $window.alert() and Javascript alert() are the same. Under what conditions should we use which one of them? Or are there no difference at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is exactly the same thing - global methods in JavaScript (running in browser) are methods of the `window`. AngularJS' [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) is alias for `window` object.

> $window: A reference to the browser's window object.

Note that you may override `$window` for your tests, but in regular code both are the same.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that in tests you can mock out the $window object so that instead of using the real alert it stubs to console.log or something else. If your code called alert directly then there is no way to override the real alert so in your tests you would see alerts popping up whenever your method used an alert.

Beyond just testing, in theory you could even use an alternative provider for $window which had an extra fancy alert implementation. Imagine if you wanted to use an alert built on bootstrap dialogs. Using the $window provider would permit you to change this in one place by injecting a new implementation and none of your other code would change.

You will not see a difference in your running code (both perform identically) but loosely coupling your code like this pays off later.

Answer (score 1):

They are identical, because `$window === window`, unless you have overridden it.

Comment: That's not exactly what the docs say: *Unlike JavaScript, where names default to global window properties, Angular expressions must use $window explicitly to refer to the global window object. For example, if you want to call alert() in an expression you must use $window.alert(). This restriction is intentional. It prevents accidental access to the global state – a common source of subtle bugs.*

Comment: @cale_b True, but it seems unlikely that he has overridden `$window`, so it is a reference to the `window` object.

Comment: For me the description is pretty most saying, we think you programmers don't know how to handle window properly. And we create a fresh clean `$window` object for your mess. But @cale_b is right look like they are the same